# How to fetch specific object from a set in Java

Tags: java, groovy, set

I would like quickly to fetch from Java Set the object equal to existing one. Is there any faster way than iterating for all elements of the set?

Here is my code:

```
class A {
    int a,b,c,d;

    public A(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result + a;
        result = prime * result + b;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
            return false;
        if (a != other.a)
            return false;
        if (b != other.b)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private Main getOuterType() {
        return Main.this;
    }

}
```

and in the code:

```
void run() {
    Set<A> a = new HashSet<>();
    a.add(new A(1,2,3,4));
    a.add(new A(2,3,4,5));

    A b = new A(1,2,3,5);
    //How to fetch from set a object equal to object b?
}
```

Is it possible to do it fast in Groovy?

Comment: You are not meant to retrieve anything from a `Set`. If your `Set` contains your object, you already have it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well you only have an equal object, not the same one.

Comment: @edgar Unless you are doing something with reference equality, what does it matter as long as they are equal?

Comment: He probably has a Set from a database or something, and wants something like `Person p = new Person("Smith, John"); Person john = set.get(p);` which has all the actual records of the Person

Comment: You could iterate over set elements, if you need to access them for something.

Comment: With Groovy, your entire class code becomes `@groovy.transform.Canonical class A { int a, b, c, d }` (so the code is reduced), but you've got the wrong datatype (as others have said) so that's not going to help (or _"...do it fast"_)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not `get` method in `java.util.Set` interface. Hence, you can not fetch an entry :)

Maybe you are using the wrong data structure. May be what you need is a `java.util.Map`?

Comment: Well, he needs a `java.util.Map` of somekind, whether it be `HashMap` or `TreeMap` (or some other sub-flavor thereof).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an object then there's no point in getting it from the Set. If you like to check if it exists in the set there is `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)`